# Tomcat 8 - Certificate Revocation List checking and caching

Tags: tomcat, ssl, caching, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I need to enable "Certificate Revocation List" checking and cache the list for a given time for a SSL/TLS HTTPS connection. The "distribution doint" is inside the accepted root certificate of the truststore. I expect, that the following line in bin/setenv.sh of tomcat enables the checking:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.security.enableCRLDP=true"
```

- Is this correct?
- How do i configure caching?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any configuration for this, @SScholl ?

Comment: @harish chava no unfortunately not.

Answer (score -1):

You can also add the option:

```
-Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=true
```

Be aware, there is a performance hit in the JSSE by doing this.